# Select k balls where l balls are white from urn

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have an urn with $n$ balls, in which there are, $r$ red balls, $b$ blue balls and $n-r-b$ white balls.

$k$ balls will be selected.

1) how many ways could $l$ white balls be selected (with replacement, with order)

2) how many ways could $l$ white balls be selected (with replacement, order not important)

3) how many ways could $l$ white balls be selected (without replacement, with order)

4) how many ways could $l$ white balls be selected (without replacement, order not important)

Are my answers are correct ?

1) $n^l * n^k-l$

2) $nP(k-l) * nPl$

3) $nC(k-l) * nCl$

4) $n+(k-l)-1Ck * n+l-1Ck$

Comment: I really don't understand the difference between 1) and 2).  What is "with order"?  Aren't you choosing $l$ balls and they all are white?

Comment: It would help if you explained your reasoning since that helps users of this site detect any errors you may have made.  For the first question, choose $l$ of the $k$ positions in the sequence of selections for the white balls.  Each of the remaining $k - l$ positions in the sequence can be filled with either a red ball or a blue ball in $2^{k - l}$ ways, giving $\binom{k}{l}2^{k - l}$ such selections.